# IText 2 + Flying Saucer: how to avoid that the images appears broken between two pdf's pages?

Tags: pdf-generation, itext, flying-saucer

i have an html file and i'm using Itext 2 with flying Saucer to convert it to a pdf file.

The problem is that if an image starts near the page end, flying saucer render a portion of it it the end of the current page and the rest in the beginning of the next page.

How to say that i want the entire image on one page only?

Answer (score 5):

You can add this to your print css:

```
img {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

The [user guide (PDF)](https://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html) mentions it.

Comment: Adam - I noticed that you're one of the top posters for flying-saucer issues - I have created a chat room for iText/flying-saucer issues since I'm sick of posting questions on it - I'm wondering if you wouldn't mind taking a look at it - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8945/itext

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a bug in FlyingSaucer that is causing issues with page-break-inside: avoid.

The issue manifests when css: orphans kicks in, when a paragraph is laid out towards the end of a page and the minimum number of lines cannot be rendered on the page. Then the block box layout state machine appears to go wrong.

We have pushed a fix to a fork here: https://github.com/krokiet/flyingsaucer/tree/master

At some point we will raise a pull request to get this merged back into the main code base.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem but

```
img {page-break-inside: avoid;}
```

is not the final solution. Yes it has impact for result and in some situations it works but not always. 
Here is some more details about the same or similar problem. 
[Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882592/embaded-images-are-breaked-between-pdf-pages-in-flaying-saucer)